# Define function with a function as image

Tags: math-mode

I would like to define a function with a function as image; something similar to what follows but I suspect that `array` isn't the best structure to do that

```
\begin{array}{}
f:&A&\to& L(B)\\
&h&\mapsto& f_h:&B&\to& B\\
&&&&x&\mapsto& 2x
\end{array}
```

(I don't know how to render latex code in this forum so I just posted the code).
I really appreciate any kind of help :)

Comment: You [cannot](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths) render LaTeX at this forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use nested `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
f\colon
\begin{aligned}[t]
A&\to L(B)\\
h &\mapsto f_h \colon
               \begin{aligned}[t]
               B &\to B\\
               x &\mapsto 2x
               \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]